# How to transform the duration into a date format with quarters?

Tags: r, date

I have a dealscan dataset, with the start and end date of the loan, and the corresponding duration of the loan in months.

I would need to get the dates for the duration of the loan, or the period between the start and end date of the loan. E.g. if the start date is 20100101 and end date is 20101231, and the duration is 12 months, I would need to get data with 2010Q1, 2010Q2, 2010Q3 and 2010Q4 that would correspond with the loan quarters.

I think I would need to create a loop for that, but it's not really working...

And such a function doesn't work either

```
df <- mutate(seq(as.Date("FacilityStartDate"), length = "Maturity", by = "quarters"))
```

Does anybody know the solution?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `as.yearqtr` from the `zoo` package. `zoo::as.yearqtr(Sys.Date())` returns `"2021 Q2"`.

Comment: I think `mutate` is supposed to operate on a `data.frame`-related object, not on a `Date` object. I'm inferring your strings are actually column names, is that correct? It would help if we had a reproducible question, as it stands this is incorrect code for `as.Date` and `mutate`.